# Issue with recalling methods

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

I am making a battleships game. I want to place 3 boats of 3 tiles in length without them overlapping. I have written the following code:

```
var boatGrid = {

    placeBoat : function() {
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            console.log("boat placed now");
            this.selectPos();
            document.getElementById("boattest").innerHTML = boatPos;
            if (document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat == 1) {
                this.placeBoat();
                document.getElementById("boattest").innerHTML = "failed";
            }
            else {
                this.buildBoat();           
            }
        }
    },

    selectPos : function() { 
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
    },

    buildBoat : function() {
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            xPos = xPos + 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            console.log("placed one tile");
        }

    },

    clearTable : function() {
        for (y = 1; y < 11; y++) {
            for (x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
                boatPos = "cell_" + x + "_" + y;
                document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat = 0;
                document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHere = 0;
                document.getElementById(boatPos).style.backgroundColor = "#34B0D9"
                document.getElementById(boatPos).innerHTML = "<pre>     </pre>";
                boatGrid.hasChecked = 0;
            }
        }
    },
}
```

When a coordinate is chosen twice (the variable boatPos stores the coordinate), the function placeBoat() is supposed to recall itself. However, what is actually happening is that the buildBoat() function is being called twice. Can any of you see the problem? I currently think it is a problem with having the placeBoat() function having to recall itself from inside, but I don't know how to get around that. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store boatPos as global variable inside boatGrid, like that:

```
var boatGrid = {
    boatPos: 0,

     placeBoat : function() {
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            //same code as before
            if (this.boatPos == 1) {
                this.placeBoat();
            // same code as before
        }
    },

    buildBoat : function() {
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            //same code as before
            this.boatPos = 1;
            // same code as before
        }
    },
}
```

And if you need to store more properties in boatPos (as it seems), use an object :

```
boatPos = {
   hasBoat: 0,
},
```

And then, in the functions:

```
if (this.boatPos.hasBoat == 1)
```

and

```
this.boatPos.hasBoat = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think it's legal to declare a variable inside an object definition like that. Did you mean to make it a property?

Comment: @Andbdrew Yes, I was a bit fast. I edited the answer to match the code.

Comment: boatPos is defined outside the object, and anyway, why would that make it run the buildBoat() function twice?

Comment: I don't know how you call your functions, but my 2 cents: I guess buildBoat is called once, and as `document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat = 1;` does not work, when calling placeBoat, hasBoat is always 0, so buildBoat is called a second time in placeBoat. Have you tried to add some `console.log()` to get the value of hasBoat, and see when and from where buildBoat is called ?